# how to know data or content is loaded into an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have a situation where I have many `JavaScript` dependencies and I don't know from which AJAX call `<form>` default `submission` is `prevented`,  most of them are `cdn` , and `success message` loads into a `<p id="contentLoadsHereFirst"></p>`.

Here I have used `setTimeout()` for `demo` only i `really` don't know when `ajax call` will finish.

Hint to me (AJAX finished): `content` will load into `<p id="contentLoadsHereFirst"></p>`

My question is how to make `$('#message').text('');` when `data` is loaded into  `<p id="contentLoadsHereFirst"></p>`  here i have used `setTimeout()` for **demo** only.

Here is code snippet and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gevs9Lky/5/):

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#message').text('Please wait.........');
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('#contentLoadsHereFirst').text('Message Has Been Sent Successfully');
   },1500);
  //my pseudo code
  
 /*if($('#contentLoadsHereFirst').html() != ''){
    $('#message').text(''); 
  }*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" id="submit">

<p id="contentLoadsHereFirst"></p>

<p style="color:red;" id="message"></p>
```

Comment: the jquery ajax method has a success callback where you can hide the loading message

Comment: i'm using some `plugin` which `takes over` on every `submit`. i don't know from where

Comment: you can use https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: i'm using some external `cdn` `ajax request` i don't know much configuration option.  so i'm trying this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) has a success callback where you can hide the loading message .

For your snippet you could add the block of code that hide the message within the setTimeout function.

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#message').text('Please wait.........');
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('#contentLoadsHereFirst').text('Message Has Been Sent Successfully');
  if($('#contentLoadsHereFirst').html() != ''){
    $('#message').text(''); 
  }
   },1500);
  //my pseudo code
  
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" id="submit">

<p id="contentLoadsHereFirst"></p>

<p style="color:red;" id="message"></p>
```

Another solution is to attach a global handler to the ajax (more details here  https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ )

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "ajax/test.html" ) {//a way to filter the responses
   $('#message').text(''); //here you ca hide your div
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code format:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); 
   $.ajax({
        url: 'Your Action Link',
        data: {},//additional data
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function () { 
          $('#message').text('Please wait......'); 
        },
       success: function (response) { 
          $('#contentLoadsHereFirst').text(response.message);
       },
      error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) { 
         console.log(error.messge);
      }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: i know this code but i don't know from where `ajax call` is `initialized`.  hope you understood

Comment: [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) please check the link hope it will help you out.